# Single Page with a scroll Widget Placement

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart

I'm trying to build a scrollable page like this:

[image]

But I always ended up like this:

[image]

I wanted to show my card widget a little bit below and then I'm going to add the other widgets below. I used different components for making this layout because of that I'm not going to paste all the code. Here is my code which I tried to create my layout:

```
Widget _buildBody(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints viewportConstraints) {
        return SingleChildScrollView(
          child: ConstrainedBox(
            constraints:
                BoxConstraints(minHeight: viewportConstraints.maxHeight),
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                _buildTitleBar(context),
                _buildCard(context),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    )
```

Comment: can you explain what exactly do you want?

Comment: I want a page which can be scrollable, has a title bar (which is blue in the images above), a card widget that has graphs on it and overflows a little bit onto the title bar

Comment: Basically I want to learn how the Stack widgets work its parent relations and I want to learn how I can customize positioning that stack's widgets

Comment: there is a workaround solution, you can do is use margin on the top for Card slight greater to the title size you want.

Comment: thanks, I'm going to try it now

Comment: wrap Card with Positioned widget and add top

Comment: Thanks but Krish's answer made my day, later on the project if there's some problems again I'm going to use your solution too.